# numpy - conditional change with closest elements

Tags: python, numpy

In a numpy array, I want to replace every occurrences of 4 where top and left of them is a 5.

so for instance :

```
0000300 
0005000
0054000
0000045
0002050
```

Should become :

```
0000300
0005000
0058000
0000045
0002000
```

I'm sorry I can't share what I tried, that's a very specific question.

I've had a look at things like

```
map[map == 4] = 8
```

And `np.where()` but I have really no idea about how to check nearby elements of a specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might seem tricky, but an `and` between three shifted versions of the matrix will work, you simply need to shift the x==5 array to the bottom, and another version of it shifted to the right, the third matrix is the x==4.

```py
first_array = np.zeros(x.shape,dtype=bool)
second_array = np.zeros(x.shape,dtype=bool)
equals_5 = x == 5
equals_4 = x == 4
first_array[1:] = equals_5[:-1] # shift down
second_array[:,1:] = equals_5[:,:-1] # shift right 
third_array = equals_4 # put it as it is.
# and operation on the 3 arrays above
results = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(first_array,second_array),third_array)
x[results] = 8
```

now `results` will be the needed logical array.
and it's an O(n) algorithm, but it scales badly if the requested pattern is very complex, not that it's not doable.